# MPAndroidChart changing data values while zooming

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I would like to ask if in MPAndroidChart there is a way to change the values of the chart while zooming, For example the first Bar chart view the values in by month when zoom in the value will change to by weeks then when zoom in again the value will change to by days then vice versa. I hope this will be done in MPAndroidChart. TYI

Comment: please share solution , if you handle this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is surely possible, you just will have to write the logic/behaviour of the chart yourself.

It is possible to listen to gestures on the chart (like zooming or scaling) via the `OnChartGestureListener`.

More on that in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart).

Comment: can you share your solution @Philipp Jahoda